# JQgrids link to an other view

Tags: jqgrid

1. I have a column with Company Names, all items in column are links.
2. I have a column with CompanyIds
3. Each of those links have to send to the same View, but link have to attach its own companyId so i can use it in my view, since i need to do some stuff with companys data.

ive found that i can use this:

edittype:'select', formatter:'showlink', formatoptions:{baselinkurl:'EditReferance.cshtml'}

but it keep saying that my EditReference  view does not excists.

My two columns:

name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 50, key: true, editable: true, editrules: { edithidden: false }, hidden: true },
            { name: 'FirmaNavn', index: 'FirmaNavn', width: 100, align: 'center', editable: false, edittype:'select', formatter:'showlink', formatoptions:{ baselinkurl:'@Url.Action("EditReferance")'}},

Comment: Could you include an example (at least one row) of the data which you post back to the jqGrid during the filling of the grid? Could you additionally write HTML fragment which you try to receive?

Comment: ive updated main question with 2 rows, ive tyred with baselinkurl, which supose to send me futher to next view, but it doesnt, it says that that path does not excists

Comment: What I need is that you write the exact format of the `<a>` element which you need to have. For example, that you need to have `<a href="/Home/EditReferance?CompanyId=123">Microsoft</a>` in the 'Company Names' column if one has `123` in the `CompanyIds` hidden column. So you want have the link `<a href="/Home/EditReferance?CompanyId=123">Microsoft</a>` for the data {CompanyId:123, Company:"Microsoft"}.

Comment: for my format it will look like <a href="/Reference/EditReferance?id=123">Sovsens</a> thats 1 line i just dont know how to auto generate it for jqgrid, and how to extract id on controller side. thank you for using so much time for me oleg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but I don't see any important different between the code from your answer and the code from your question. The 'showlink' formatter construct the following string `op.baseLinkUrl+op.showAction + '?'+ op.idName+'='+opts.rowId+op.addParam` (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.1.2/js/jquery.fmatter.js#L299)). So if you use `baseLinkUrl: '@Url.Action("EditReferance")'` or `baseLinkUrl: '', showAction: '@Url.Action("EditReferance")'` you will have the same results.

You real problem was that you used **wrong case **in the names of property `baseLinkUrl` of the [showlink](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3apredefined_formatter#predefined_format_types) formatter. Instead of

```
formatter: 'showlink', formatoptions: {baseLinkUrl: '@Url.Action("EditReferance")'}
```

you used

```
formatter: 'showlink', formatoptions: {baselinkurl: '@Url.Action("EditReferance")'}
```

Comment: yesh, its one of my stupid small mistakes... i write faster then i think... but uve got the right answer ofc.

Comment: @Timsen: You are welcome! As I have seen your answer I wondered and only at the moment I could see that you wrote the `baseLinkUrl` instead of `baselinkurl`. Sometime such kind of errors is very difficult to find because one can not always see there.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer was very simple,
your column should look like this:

{ name: 'FirmaNavn', index: 'FirmaNavn', width: 100, align: 'center', editable: false, edittype:'select', formatter:'showlink', formatoptions:{ baselinkurl:'', showAction: '@Url.Action("EditReferance")'}}

hope it helps to someone

Comment: If you want to recive Id in the view again u can simply write string s = Request["id"]; which will return the id from url